# Importing svg file

Tags: import

[image: when i go to edit mode i c many many edges and vertex and faces. Is there other way or other extension to get a simple geometry with less edges and faces so that my object will be light weight]
i have made this object inkscape and export to svg format. I load the object and converted to mesh Alt+C and when i go to edit mode i c many many edges and vertex and faces. Is there other way or other extension to get a simple geometry with less edges and faces so that my object will be light weight

Comment: You could delete all faces, select all vertices, and pressing F you'll get one big n-gon face. This simplifies mesh view in particular after extrusion. Then you could subdivide it or ese... But if your svg has many curves, that means many vertices are needed to represent it as mesh...

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the vertice count, go into the curves shape properties and reduce the **Preview U** value, before converting the curve to a mesh.

[image]